# Error Incomprensible "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'La operación se completó correctamente'"

Tags: c#

Me salta este error cuándo estoy haciendo una lectura de una línea

```
if ((bool)lPreciosFechas.GetSelected(i) == true)
```

El caso es que la línea da como valor 0, y aplicándolo en otras líneas, no me causa problema, de hecho, en esta parte no me causa ningún problema hasta que si lo hace, y no se por qué ¿A qué puede ser debido y como se corrige?

La cadena lPreciosFechas.Items[i].ToString() tiene un valor de "XX##26/11/2022~29/11/2022&&Camarote InteriorXXX400XXX1", es decir, tiene valor

Comment: ¿Por qué parsea el retorno de una función cuando ya es de tipo boolean?. [enlace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.getselected?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). Lea la documentación quizá encuentre solución al aparente error.

Comment: Y proporcione más datos para quien trate de ayudarlo sea lo más fácil posible. Indique por ejemplo que está usando un listbox.  Y el error de consola no lo ponga en el título, que aparte no muestra nada especifico de que fué.

Comment: vale, me lo apunto